# IFrame error XFrame Options to Samesite in Local

Tags: javascript, html

**I'm trying to get the specific section of the page using iframe.**

The exact `<section>` is defined as `#main` only. So I can get the content of the section

```
  <div id="my-div">
     <iframe src="https://www.whitelabs.com/stores/?radius=25&" id="main" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
```

**But I'm getting error like this on my local**

[image]

**Tried to add these different code on my htaccess but seems not working**

Option1

```
 Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Option 2

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is whitelabs.com your site? If not you can't override the headers they set on their server. If they decide they don't want their site displayed in iframe that's their prerogative

Comment: I have the files of the site. Seems like you are correct will take a look if it blocks me